# Read app configfile entry in multiple projects which is in the common class library

Tags: vb.net

I have a common class library project which has code to read  entry from the app config file which is in the same class library.

Now, i would like to read the entry in multiple other projects by instantiating the class library .

Note:- don't suggest to add the App.Config file to the main solution and not in the class library project :-)which know. But as stated above my requirement is different.

Comment: Can you just add a method to the class library that returns the entry from the config file?

Comment: @Daniel, yes, i added a method to the class library to return entry but when i called class library method from test windows application, the entry from class library config will not be read, instead the appconfig entry from test windows application will be read.

Comment: Oh I see! Class libraries can't have config files, or at least they won't be published with the library.  You could consider adding a custom "config" file to your library and read from that, but you will have to implement the logic for it yourself.